# Logging a mysql permissions error

Tags: mysql, permissions

Using MySQL 5.1 on CentOS 6.5. - our application cannot write to a particular table. I am able to execute the statements via the Heidi SQL console, but I can't figure out what else it could be besides permissions.

I've checked the permissions and they look ok:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, EXECUTE, SHOW VIEW ON `messaging`.* TO 'messaging'@'%'
```

These are the same permissions the user has in the test environment, where the inserts and updates go through ok. We currently do not have adequate logging in the client code that makes the insert/update calls, so I was hoping to get a permissions denied message in a mysql log.

I've activated general logging like so:

```
set global general_log = 1;
```

And when it's on I can see the select statements in the general_log table, but no inserts, and no errors.

Is there another type of logging I can activate to see when a user makes a call that does not succeed?

Comment: have you tried logging into the db with that user's permissions directly and see what you can/can't do?

Comment: @MarcB yes, if I log into the db via Heidi, with that user, I can run the INSERT statement. Back in the application I can see the data, and the SELECT statement shows up in the general_log.